# Diameter of a circle using 3 nonlinear points

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]I am trying to find the diameter of a circle using 3 points on its circumference.  2 of the points are 5 feet from eachother while the third point is centered between the other 2.  The ceter point is 1 foot from a line drawn between the other 2 points.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If two chords $AB$ and $CD$ of a circle intersect at $P$, then $AP\cdot PB=CP\cdot PD$.  Draw the diameter joining the red and green lines in your diagram. So, $AP=PB=\dfrac{5}{2}$ and $CP=1$, and hence $DP=\dfrac{25}{4}$. Now you can compute the diameter. 
[image]

Comment: So just to ensure that I did everything right that would make the diameter 6.25 correct?  Just so you know this is for a real world application rather than homework.  I am very glad that this is not homework, lol.

Comment: I think it should be 7.25

Comment: because $CP=1$ and diameter $=CP+PD=1+\dfrac{25}{4}$

Comment: dang it...ok so AP*PB=CP*PD   That means 2.5*2.5=1*PD correct?  Assuming that is correct it would be 6.25/1=PD correct? Ohh...oops.  I solved for PD and never added CP back in, lol.  Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: its ok.. mistakes do happen. Please consider accepting my answer if you find it useful!!

Comment: Your help was extremely helpful and I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you may use of following property:
"The circumcenter of a triangle can be found as the intersection of any two of the three perpendicular bisectors."

Adjust your figure accordingly and search for similar triangles.

Answer (score 0):

So you have an arc whose chord is l=5 feet long and the **sagitta** is s=1 fooot.
See Wikipedia article [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagitta_(geometry)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagitta_%28geometry%29)